# Mirth Connect Version 3.5.0.8232 Cannot Start Service

Tags: java, mirth, mirth-connect

I installed Mirth Connect version 3.5.0.8232 on a Window 7 Ultimate 64 bit OS. It appeared to be installed successfully. However, I clicked on Start to start the Mirth Connect service, and it gave the error message "The Mirth Connect Service could not be started." I checked the log file, and it had the exception message. Looking at the server Manager, it looked like the service did start because the start button is disable and the restart, stop, refresh, and administrator are enable. Does anyone has an idea how to resolve this issue?

If I clicked on the Administrator button, it gave the following message (will post the exception message for the administrator screen at the very bottom):

```
Could not load file/URL specified: http://localhost:8080/webstart.jnlp?maxHeapSize=512m
```

**Log file error message**

```
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,608 [Main Server Thread] Server: Exception in thread "Main Server Thread" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,610 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:384)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,611 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.statistic.CounterStatistic.<init>(CounterStatistic.java:35)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,611 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager.<init>(AbstractSessionManager.java:136)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,611 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager.<init>(HashSessionManager.java:124)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,611 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.<init>(SessionHandler.java:70)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,611 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.newSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:297)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,612 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:392)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,612 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.relinkHandlers(ServletContextHandler.java:200)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,612 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:172)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,612 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:266)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,612 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:211)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,612 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at com.mirth.connect.server.MirthWebServer.<init>(MirthWebServer.java:202)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,613 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth.startWebServer(Mirth.java:376)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,613 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth.startup(Mirth.java:252)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,613 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth.run(Mirth.java:153)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,614 [Main Server Thread] Server: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)CallSite/invokeStatic
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,614 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:763)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,614 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:880)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,615 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1037)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,615 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1341)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,615 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:382)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,615 [Main Server Thread] Server:  ... 14 more
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,615 [Main Server Thread] Server: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,616 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,616 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:852)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,616 [Main Server Thread] Server:  at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:877)
ERROR 2017-05-04 13:14:44,616 [Main Server Thread] Server:  ... 17 more
```

Administrator Error:

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: http://localhost:8080/webstart.jnlp?maxHeapSize=512m]
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

When I clicked on Wrapped Exception tab, it showed this exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to using an incompatible JRE. Make sure you're using the official Oracle JRE version 8 or higher. What specific version are you using now?

Make sure also that if you're running the 64-bit distribution of Mirth Connect, use the 64-bit version of Java.

Comment: that was it. It never crossed my mind to make sure that the JRE is a 64 bit version. It's working as expected now.